# Angular 1.2 - replace directive with global settings

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive which is replace a specific date (is a flag) with a string.

```
app.directive('dateToText', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            if(scope.currentUserData.selectedLanguage == 'FR') {
                scope.unKnownDate  = 'Date inconnue'
            }
            else {
                scope.unKnownDate = 'Date unknown';
            }
            $timeout(function(){
                if(attrs.value == "01/01/2050" && $(el).prop('disabled')) {
                    console.log("attrs.value: ", attrs.value );
                    $(el).val(scope.unKnownDate);
                }
            });

        }
    }
}]);
```

This directive is used for some inputs, but I want to use this logic globally, not to put for every input this directive.

All inputs which are disabled and have value="01/01/2050" must be with value="My text".

Thanks for any idea!

Comment: use angular filter approach.

Answer (score 0):

I create this directive and the problem was solved:

```
.directive('dateToText', ['$timeout', '$interpolate', function($timeout, $interpolate) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {

            if(scope.currentUserData.selectedLanguage == 'FR') {
                scope.unKnownDate  = 'Inconnue'
            }
            else {
                scope.unKnownDate = 'Unknown';
            }
            $timeout(function(){
                if(attrs.value == "01/01/2050") {
                    console.log("attrs.value: ", attrs.value );
                    $(el).val(scope.unKnownDate);
                }
                if( el[0].textContent.trim() == "01/01/2050" ) {
                    $(el).text(scope.unKnownDate);
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });

        }
    }
}])
```